# Azure Monitor Custom log search Query - understanding Period and Frequency

Tags: azure, monitor, alerts

**UPDATE**:

the actual problem is different from what I've described. I'll provide and update/edit to this ticket once we'll resolve the issue. More details may be found at this thread - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Log-Analytics/Reliably-trigger-alerts-for-Log-Analytics-log-entries/m-p/319315/highlight/false#M1224

**Original question**:

We use `Azure Monitor` to create alerts based on logs in `Log Analytics`. For this we choose our Log Analytics account as a "RESOURCE", then choose "Custom log search" signal name for "CONDITION". Alert logic - "Number of results greater than 0".

Sample query:

```
search *
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY" and status_s == "Failed"
```

For `Period` and `Frequency` lets set `15` minutes. All looks simple, but...

**The issue**: described above setup does not work (it works *sometimes*), because alerts are fired only sometimes, a lot of them are missed which is completely unacceptable behavior.

If we set `Period = Frequency = 5` minutes we basically miss almost every event. `Period = Frequency = 15` minutes works better, but still a lot of events are missing. `Period = Frequency = 30` works even better, but all this looks weird.

**Important notice** - logs are collected from `Data Factory V2` into `Log Analytics`. I suspect that alert misses are due to the fact that logs are delivered to `Log Analytics` with some delay (up to several minutes). So  when `Azure Monitor` evaluates alert query for the last `15` minutes (`Period=15`) it might be that most resent log entries are still not in `Log Analytics`. When next query evaluation is executed in `15` minutes **it will miss the logs that were ingressed with a delay for prev `15` minutes interval**. Is this assumption correct? If so, this is very weird - how then we supposed to configure `Period` and `Frequency` values? If I set `Period > Frequency` (e.g. `Period = 30` and `Frequency = 5,` which means "evaluate expression every 5 minutes, take data for last 30 minutes from current time") then we get multiple duplicated alerts because `Period` is larger than `Frequency` so there is a big chance of log search query returning the same log entries every `5` minutes - this is highly undesirable behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue happened to be with a buggy bahavior of ARM template creating alerts. Thanks to Stanislav Zhelyazkov it has been nailed down and resolved - I use alternative ARM API now and it seems to work fine. More details on the topic may be found here - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Log-Analytics/Reliably-trigger-alerts-for-Log-Analytics-log-entries/m-p/309610.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and this post has helped us out: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/handling-ingestion-delay-in-azure-sentinel-scheduled-alert-rules/ba-p/2052851

In short, we've now setup a log alert that runs every 15 minutes and uses data for the past 30 minutes (Bicep/ARM: frequencyInMinutes=15, timeWindowInMinutes=30). Also, I've added a where statement to our query where the `ago(15m)` should be equal to the frequency of the alert:

```
| where ingestion_time() > ago(15m) // Source: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/handling-ingestion-delay-in-azure-sentinel-scheduled-alert-rules/ba-p/2052851
```

This should solve your alerts not being fired because of ingestion delays but also prevent duplicates.